# Magento #page-login

Tags: jquery, css, magento, admin

I added a custom background to my login page and I want it to fade in by using jQuery. My question is **where is the** admin **head file** that I need to import into my theme and edit? [image]

Answer (score 3):

The page you want to personalize is `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml`. Modifying `head.phtml` would impact all pages that require it (opinion, not verified).

So why not copy override `login.phtml` with your own, this way you also avoid messing with core files. I personalized the content of the backend login screen.

In the above path, you see `default/default/` standing for `packagename/themename/`. `Packagename` should be left to 'default' since there is no "base" package to fall back on for `Magento`. You create `mythemename/` inside of the default package, in which you put your copy of `login.phtml`.

`app/design/adminhtml/default/mythemename/template/mylogin.phtml`. (Note, i renamed my file to `mylogin.phtml` instead of `login.phtml`; not sure if it's useful, but in file access logs or when reading xml code, it seems easier for debugging purposes)

You then have to indicate that `Magento` should look in your theme before using the default one (in your `etc/config.xml file`):

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>mythemename</default>
            </theme>
            <!-- CAN CUSTOMIZE THEME FOR EACH OF THESE SEPARATELY -->
            <!--<layout>-->
                <!--<default>mythemename</default>-->
            <!--</layout>-->
            <!--<template>-->
                <!--<default>mythemename</default>-->
            <!--</template>-->
            <!--<skin>-->
                <!--<default>mythemename</default>-->
            <!--</skin>-->
            <!--<locale>-->
                <!--<default>mythemename</default>-->
            <!--</locale>-->
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

In `adminhtml`'s `layout/main.xml` you can see that the following handle is responsible for the backend's login screen : `<adminhtml_index_login>`. So you want to override this.
To do so (I'm not sure yet exactly why this is necessary. Anyone else can detail further ?) You need to specify in your `etc/config.xml` that you update the layout for this handle:

```
<config>
    ...
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <adminhtml_index_login>
                    <file>mythemename.xml</file>
                </adminhtml_index_login>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    ...
</config>
```

As you see, you will need to create your own `layout/` folder and place a new file inside (`mythemename.xml`) : `/app/design/adminhtml/default/mythemename/layout/mythemename.xml`.
Inside, you have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_index_login>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="content" template="mylogin.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info" />
            </block>
        </block>
    </adminhtml_index_login>
</layout>
```

This should do it. About javascript or jquery code, I don't know if you could inject it in the page itself? (make the code load the image, then let it appear) Then you don't need to touch the headers at all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml`.

Hope it helps.