# Override adminhtml phtml files

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to override below mentioned phtml file to my module Iksula/CustomOrderStatus:

```
C:\Users\Iksula769\AppData\Local\Temp\scp25841\var\domains\sonicsense\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\info.phtml
```

Can anyone tell me how do i do that?
Please provide proper stepwise solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try the following blog to override phtml file

http://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/how-to-overwrite-sales-view-order-phtml-file-in-magento/

and the following

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/how_to_customize_backend_template_f.e._sales_order_information

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your answer and not just links. The links can expire and the answer would be useless.

Comment: Links have expired

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following answer I posted. It explains the steps (with file path, and content) of how to override the adminhtml's login.phtml file.

It answers your question about 'how?', though not exactly for the template file you mention.

See my answer on this topic : [Magento #page-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276048/magento-page-login/20854521#20854521)